# How we can use .net assemblies without installing .net framework by Native Delphi?

Tags: .net, delphi, linker, native

In [this post](http://www.nickhodges.com/post/Blast-from-the-Past-Why-You-Should-Choose-Delphi.aspx) nick hodges wrote: "Delphi can link .Net code into your EXE".
How we can do It? Is it exists any example about this delphi Capability?

Comment: If you have a .NET assembly, you can import it, if you use Delphi 2010 or later, from Component-Import Component menu

Comment: The component-import menu works with ActiveX components, not .net components.

Comment: @Warren: The .Net assembly would need to be a COM wrapper.

Comment: Ah, in that case, maybe it's still possible.

Comment: Please note that that post was a "Blast from the Past", written six years ago about the now defunct Delphi for .Net.  Thus your question is moot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read the comments under the article you linked, you can read that this was a feature of the now defunct delphi.NET (delphi8 if I remember correctly).
Even if this would be possible you would still have the dependency on the .NET framework.

So the answer to your question is: **not possible**

Comment: Note that unlike the otherwise equally defunct Kylix, Delphi for .NET is still available as part of the older versions offer you get with most RAD Studio purchases.

Comment: I doubt that a .Net assembly can be run without (as the question title says) 'installing .NET Framework', even Delphi .NET will not be able to work without the framework.

Comment: @mjn: Yes indeed :) Updated my answer

Answer (score 5):

You can use regular COM components, written in C# and with the interface defined as ComVisible(true).

Another more direct import of C# assemblies in a Delphi executable is possible with [Managed VCL](http://www.managed-vcl.com/).

Managed VCL can:

- Create .Net objects from assemblies not registered for COM, using assembly name or location,  and loading .Net assemblies from streams;
- Create and use .Net objects that are not COM visible;
- Create .Net objects using parametrized constructors;
- Call properties/methods/fields of .Net object including static properties/methods/fields;
- Handle .Net exceptions and get all .Net exception properties including exception type name, StackTrace etc.;
- Get information about loaded instance of .Net framework such as memory usage and size of heap by generation;
- Load needed .Net runtime and even select which version of runtime to use on startup;
- Place .Net controls on VCL Win32 form;
- Use ADO.Net datasources as TDataSet descendants in Win32 applications. ADO.Net will be native and most supported API for SQL Server 2005 (Yukon);
- Host ASP.Net pages and services;
- Embed .Net assemblies into Win32 application as resources.

It is much low level than Hydra, which is more about sharing UI between the two platform, whereas Managed VCL is truly about hosting a DotNet CLR machine in the Delphi process, then access to it via its own classes. It is amazing work!

Answer (score 3):

There is a commercial solution "hydra". http://www.remobjects.com/hydra/

Another possibility is to use COM interop. To embedd the .NET Source you could store the assembly as a resource file and write it later to disc, if you need a single .exe file.

Comment: I am using RemObjects Hydra and Atoze Cross-Talk in many of projects. but It is very important for me, wich my native exe file can be use  .net codes without installing .net framework(for old version of windows, for example win Xp without any service pack!)! .net is good but for basic users It is't good(installing, crashing and etc)! I think uing .net in Desktop project can Increase support problems!

Comment: @Shaahin What on earth are you talking about? You want .net but you don't want .net. What you are asking for is nonsense.

Comment: @David, I can't speak english very well, I am sury. I think .net classes are very rich but .net based applications are Not easy to Deploy to the end users. my customers have very basic information about computer! if I can combine Delphi and .net we can create most powerfull applications. but we can't do It, becuse It have very side effects for supporting department(-many of computer viruses can crash .net- if users change the os they must .net framework again and many of reasons).@David, It is very bad wich I can not speak english. for solving this problem I going to learn english language.

Comment: @ShaahinAshayeri If you want to program against .net, you need to deploy .net.

Answer (score 3):

The article Nick wrote refers to a now nearly obsolete old version of Delphi.  When Delphi 2006 and 2007 shipped as part of "RAD Studio" they included three "personalities":

- Delphi
- Delphi.net
- C++ Builder

The .net personality was dropped as a shipping product, and no longer appear in the "2009" release, or any subsequent release, but it may interest you to know that the underlying technology that provided "Delphi.net 2007" to you is still used inside Delphi XE3, because delphi itself depends on .net assemblies. In other words, Embarcadero still uses "Delphi .net" internally, but doesn't provide it to you.  That's not because they're stingy, it's because "Delphi.net" is no longer important as a product, and .Net is no longer the "future of all new Microsoft APIs".

Microsoft spent a lot of energy making everyone afraid of .Net.   Not only did everyone have to embrace it, Microsoft claimed that .net would be the new default way of producing Windows APIs.  As delphi was at the time only a Windows product, and as Delphi is still mostly used to produce Windows applications, the developers of a Windows-only tool could not afford to ignore Microsoft's stated intentions.  .Net was the future.

Even inside Microsoft that idea died a much needed death.   The office team, and the Windows team did not drink the .net kool-aid, and .net is now just one more layer of stuff in windows.

These days,  no facility is provided "in the box" in Delphi to produce or consume .net assemblies in any product version after 2007.  However, third party solutions exist.

While somebody commented "you can still get Delphi.net 2007 as part of the older-versions offer" you get with most RAD studio purchases, however it's not recommended to try starting out in Delphi.net at this late date.

For pure .net programming using Delphi-like syntax, try Delphi Prism.     For interfacing between .net code and Delphi native code, within the same process try RemObjects Hydra.  For interfacing between .net code and Delphi code in different processes, try RemObjects SDK.

As far as Nick's statements, he posted at the top of his blog that this was a very old blog post being reposted for historical value.  That's what his statements mean; They were current when first posted, and time has marched on a bit since then.

**Update** Bruce has kindly pointed out that the comments about the component-import technique may still apply if you have created a COM component using .net. You could then use COM interop to make a special .net assembly that could be used via COM, from Delphi, but I have never done that, and so I am not going to attempt it here.

Comment: I found a tool for solving this problem at http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/. but in this case my host app programmed in native delphi and I want create library in dotnet. In this web site located a dot net app demo. this demo runs without installing dotnet, but It is a exe file. I don't know wich this tools can works with dot net Library or Not?! I am going to testing It...

Comment: @Shaahin This is just silly. That tool has nothing to do with the question you asked. You asked if Delphi could link managed .net code into a native exe. The answer is no. That tool does something completely different. You should consider editing the question so that it asks what you really want to ask.

Comment: @David, This solution is sufficient for me. and  I am changing my question. thanx...

Comment: @ShaahinAshayeri: don't change your question please, ask a NEW question. This question has been answered...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [AToZed CrossTalk](http://www.atozed.com/crosstalk/).

> What is CrossTalk?
>
> CrossTalk allows native Delphi code to
>   consume and use .NET classes and libraries.
>   No changes or control is required to
>   the .NET classes. CrossTalk makes the
>   classes available so that they look like
>   native classes. No registry entries or COM
>   registration is required. Only a few DLL files
>   in your application directory are required.

Comment: Have you used this yourself?